# Typing algebraic data type with generic type

Tags: haskell

```
data List t = E | C t (List t)
  deriving Show

lst1 :: List Int
lst1 = C 2 E
```

Why is `t` typed to 2 in case ?
As the first guard defines "t = E" is this reason `(List t)` is allowed, so "C t (List t)" can also be read "C t E" ?

```
data NonEmptyList a = NEL a [a]
lst2 :: NonEmptyList = 2
```

Why can't 2 be typed to `a` as `t` is typed to 2 in above case ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the first type:

```
data List t = E | C t (List t)
```

`t` is a *type parameter*, it must be provided as an existing type.  `E` is not a type, it is a *data constructor*, or *value constructor*.  `C` is also a data constructor.  They have the types:

```
E :: List t
C :: t -> List t -> List t
```

You could construct values like

```
> E :: List Int  -- Equivalent to []
E
> C 1 E :: List Int  -- Equivalent to [1]
C 1 E
> C 1 (C 2 E) :: List Int  -- Equivalent to [1, 2]
C 1 (C 2 E)
```

And so on.  You can treat `E` as the empty list `[]` and `C` as the list constructor `:`, so `C 1 (C 2 (C 3 E))` is equivalent to `1 : 2 : 3 : []` which is the same as `[1, 2, 3]`.

In the second type:

```
data NonEmptyList a = NEL a [a]
```

You have the data constructor

```
NEL :: a -> [a] -> NonEmptyList a
```

You can construct values like

```
> NEL 1 [] :: NonEmptyList Int  -- Equivalent to [1]
NEL 1 []
> NEL 1 [2] :: NonEmptyList Int  -- Equivalent to [1, 2]
```

And so on.  This type forces you to always have at least one value, so it can't be non-empty.

When you write `lst2 :: NonEmptyList = 2`, this is a syntax error, and it's hard to guess what you meant, but the equivalent `NonEmptyList Int` to the `lst1 :: List Int` would be written as `NEL 2 [] :: NonEmptyList Int`.